# TYPO3 - How to show the user status femanager -> isOnline

Tags: plugins, typo3, fluid

i search for a solution in TYPO3 Fluid and the Ext: femanager!

how can i show the user online/offline status?

femanager database "isOnline", but this field is all the time on FALSE

But in the TYPO3 Backend in the femanager modus, is the right status "online".
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/femanager/Introduction/Index.html#backend-manage-frontend-users

Thanks for help.

Comment: i found a solution:
https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/femanager/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/UserBackend/List.html#L81

this FLUID works perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the Solution](https://github.com/TYPO3-extensions/femanager/blob/master/Resources/Private/Templates/UserBackend/List.html#L81)

put this Fluid/HTML in the new Fluid-Template, and it works perfect.